# Change WooCommerce Gateway Display Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I goggled a lot but didn't find an answer.

My Problem is : 
I developed a custom Woo-commerce payment gateway and added it's settings under checkout tab in Woo-commerce settings panel. 
Now i want that my custom payment gateway should be at top on checkout page. 
So how i can do that?

I don't want to do that by doing drag and drop on checkout options page.

I want that when i install and active my plug-in then using some action or hook i want to set it at top.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry I missed out that part..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

great question!

I found it,, in your plugin where you define your custom class and init it with hook for woocommerce to add actual plugin like this in mine:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_add_mk_tcom_gateway' );
```

inside function you have something like this I guess,,

only change this line:

```
/**
 * Add the Gateway to WooCommerce
 **/
function woocommerce_add_mk_tcom_gateway($methods) {
    array_unshift($methods, 'WC_MK_tcom' );
    // $methods[] = 'WC_MK_tcom';
    return $methods;
}
```

on checkout page you'll have this first option :)

hth, k

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you were bit late. I already used the same solution. But Vote UP for ur help.

Comment: Thanks for voteup, I googled it too, but with no luck also :)